# angular: asynchronously fill an array

Tags: arrays, angular, asynchronous, fill

I have an array of elements, a big one, rendered in a dropdown with `*ngFor`. Whenever I click to open the dropdown, the UI is blocked for a certain amount of time. Finally the dropdown opens and the items are all there.
It's not a big problem but I am trying to make the dropdown to instantly open on click, and the list to be filled and rendered asynchronously.

The original list is synchronously available, in a variable (it's not given from async call to server).

---

I think I should create a mirror array, starting from an empty, and write an asynchronous function to push elements from the original list to the mirror one.

What's a way to do something like that? I can't grab how to use observables for doing so.

This is my simplified setup

**Component**

```js
source = [...]; // a thousand of objects
mirror = [];    // progressively filled with source elements

async onDropdownOpen(open: boolean) {
  if (open) {
    // async fill of mirror
  } else {
    // empty mirror to boost next time dropdown opening
    mirror = [];
  }
}
```

**Template** (I am using ngBootstrap)

```html
<div
  ngbDropdown
  #dd="ngbDropdown"
  (openChange)="onDropdownOpen($event)">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
    <div *ngFor="let el of mirror">
      ... async el rendering ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: get the list when your component is being initialized, not when you click to open the dropdown. That way when the user click to open the dropdown, the server call to get the list should hopefully came back with the data already.

Comment: That's not the point. As written, the point is: the data is ready, but the list is big. Dropdown stucks for a 0.5 - 1 second when you open it, because it is probably slow on rendering a long list. I want the list to be rendered progressively.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use the Angular CDK Virtual Scroll directive.

```html
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
    <div *cdkVirtualFor="let el of mirror">
      ... async el rendering ...
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about that, could be an option. But I would like to do that without external libraries. Is it not possible to make, I don't know, an observable out of the `mirror` array, fill it and let the UI asynchronously updating?

Comment: If you want to do it without external libraries, I would say look at how the Angular Material team is implementing it with their virtual scroll. You can just copy they code into your library and modify it to do what you want. That being said, this is a really good library. I personally have implemented a virtual scroll implementation, and it is not a trivial thing.